# MySQL error message

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have imported my Access to MySQL through a program. I now want to change some of the columns from null to not null but it won't let me. An error 1265 comes up saying "data truncated for column" and the other error is error 1046, "no database selected".

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure the column that you'r trying to change to not-null doesn't contain any null values

Comment: data truncated means you stuffed more data into a field than it can handle, eg. 200 chars into a varchar(100) field.

Comment: If it says no database selected, it means you must select one before operating on tables and so on. The sentence USE DATABASE myNewDatabase, where myNewDatabase is the name of the database you created to keep the imported data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select a database

```
mysql> use myDatabase;
```

Then, update all rows to a not null value

```
mysql> UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = '' WHERE myColumn IS NULL;
```

Then, alter your table

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY COLUMN myColumn text NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE 'Your table'
SET 'your column' = ''
WHERE 'your column'  IS NULL
```

and then alter your table to set the table to set the column to `NOT NULL`.